# Toggle two different functions on a single onClick in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two different functions

```
  bookmark = () => {
//logic for bookmark
}

  bookmarkRemove = () => {
//logic for bookmark remove
}

    return (
      <div>
   <img src={bookamark} alt="bookmark" onClick={}
</div>
)
```

When I first click, I want to trigger `bookmark()`, and second time If I click the same image, it should trigger `bookmarkRemove()` and third-time bookmark() and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// local state..
state = {
 bookmark: true,
}

// execute based on the state and then toggle it..
handleBookMark = () => {
 this.state.bookMark ? bookMark() : removeBookMark();

 this.setState((prevState) => {
  ...prevState,
  bookmark:!this.state.bookmark, 
 })
}

<div onClick={() => this.handleBookMark()}>
 <img ... />
</div>
```

Comment: `this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        bookmark: !this.state.bookmark,
       
      };` - It is enclosed by return satement

Answer (score 0):

there are mutliple ways to do it, but i will use closure to demonstrate

`onClick={ toggleBookmark() }`

```js
function toggleBookmark() {
  let bookmarked  = false; // take default value from state 
  return function () {
    bookmarked ? bookmarkRemove() : bookmark();
    bookmarked = !bookmarked;
  }
}
```

now you can keep this `bookmarked` state in component as well

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: The issue is, on the next component rerender, the bookmark will return to false.

Comment: thats why i have mentioned to keep `bookmarked` in state as well

Comment: 1) you are calling it by default (mind the paranthesis) on onClick. it should be {toggleBookMark} or {() => toggleBookMark()}. 2) noted your comment and understood your logic, but it's not well written.. you can always do,  return this.state.bookmarked ? bookMark() : bookmarkRemove().. .

Comment: wanted to keep it react free

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state to check and trigger function you want.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isBookMakred, setIsBookMakred] = useState(false);
  const bookmark = () => {
    //logic for bookmark
  };

  const bookmarkRemove = () => {
    //logic for bookmark remove
  };

  const handleOnclick = () => {
    if (isBookMakred) {
      bookmarkRemove();
      setIsBookMakred(false);
    } else {
      bookmark();
      setIsBookMakred(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img src="image_url" alt="bookmark" onClick={handleOnclick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code return an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

Comment: @Dony this is just a piece of code inside a component, followed topic code.

Comment: Thanks @Dony. It's better to make a simple working code. So I have updated the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Make a `toggle` state variable, and change it whenever the function is triggered.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  function toggleFunction(){
    if(toggle) bookmarkRemove()
    else bookmark()
    setToggle(!toggle)
  }

  return (
    <img src={bookamark} alt="bookmark" onClick={toggleFunction}
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a toggle in the state

```
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true)
    bookmark = () => { setToggle(false) //other logic }
    bookmark = () => {setToggle(true) //other logic}


    return (
          <div>
       <img src={bookmark} alt="bookmark" 
    onClick={(toggle) => toggle? this.bookmark: this.bookmarkRemove}>
    </div>
    )
```